# What does this bogus route (0&0x68 c8.c8.c8.c8...) mean in my routing table?

Tags: network

This is fresh after a reboot, on a wireless network which is known to be a little flaky. The first line is unlike anything I've seen before:

```
$ netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
0&0x68             c8.c8.c8.c8.c8.c8.c8.c8.c8.8.0.0.8.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.68.80.0.5.14.4.0.f.1e.3.8.1.0.7.0.0.0.b.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7f.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.a8.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.ac.13.80.1.4.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.80.0.5.14.4.0.f.1e.5.0.6.5.3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.1.8.1.0.0.0.0.0.4.0.0.0.7f.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.a8.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.20.7.10.51 USc             9        0     en0
default            172.19.128.1       UGSc           11        0     en0
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              4      155     lo0
172.19.128/20      link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
172.19.128.1       0:b:86:61:f2:70    UHLWIir        12       14     en0   1177
172.19.129.189     127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
172.19.143.255     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        6     en0
```

The first entry is very sticky; even taking down the network interface doesn't kill it. It isn't recognized by `route delete`. I need to restart the OS to get rid of it. It makes the system entirely unusable, since it causes network connections to fail:

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
Trying 74.125.141.104...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.141.104: Cannot allocate memory
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

What's going on here, and how can I fix it when it happens without a reboot?

Comment: User `Mike` (see his comments on my answer) had a similar problem and could get rid of the bogus route without a reboot by disabling IPv4, applying changes and re-enabling it. Have you experienced the problem again?

Comment: @jaume Fortunately for me and unfortunately for StackExchange, I have not experienced it recently.

Comment: I'm happy for you. Should the problem appear again, I'd appreciate if you gave the steps in my answer a try and reported back.

Answer (score 4):

Although I couldn't reproduce it on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.8.2), [some users](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3792069?start=0&tstart=0) have reported a similar behavior, including the creation of a bogus route:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
(...)
128.0&0x8600  ff.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.5.ff.ff.ff.86.0.0.0.88.0.5.14.5.0.68.c.1.9.0.0.7.0. 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7f.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.dc.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.8d.c.5a .4f.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0. 0.0.10.2.0.0.a9.fe.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.14.12.5.0.6.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 .6.ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.0.0.7c.0.5.14.1.0.68.c.7.8.0.0.3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 .0.0.0.0.7f.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.0.40.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c0.0.0.0.c0.0.0.0.0.0.0. 0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.ac.1c.84 USc             0        4     en0
```

when putting the computer to sleep while using a VPN connection over WiFi. This doesn't seem to be your case, as you see such a route right after starting your Mac.

I can't tell you what's going wrong here, but there is a post in the link above that mentions that **it could be fixed without a reboot** like this:

> Turning off tcp/ip and turning it back on worked like a charm.

If you want to give it a try, open System Preferences, select the Network pane and, if necessary, click the lock icon to make changes:

[image]

Select your open connection from the list on the left hand side (Ethernet or WiFi), press the button <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>, select the TCP/IP tab, set Configure IPv4 to Off:

[image]

and confirm by pressing <kbd>OK</kbd>. Set TCP/IP back to its original setting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  This problem is intermittent, but next time I notice it, I'll try this and see if it helps.

Comment: Let's hope it helps. Could you report back after testing? I'm curious too...

Comment: I'm also curious. I only seem to get this on some occasions, and only when I'm running Juniper's Network Connect VPN client.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for your comment. If you can test it I'd appreciate any feedback.

Comment: @jaume - I encountered this problem again, and it resolved using the steps you suggested - I disabled IPv4 on both of my active interfaces (wifi and eth), applied the changes, then re-enabled them and the bogus route disappeared. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for your feedback, I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

To fix the issue from the command line, or remotely:

```
interfacetofix=`netstat -r -f inet | grep "0&" | awk '{print $NF}'`
interfacenametofix=`networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "$interfacetofix" -B1 | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 2-10`
networksetup -setv4off "$interfacenametofix"; networksetup -setdhcp "$interfacenametofix"
```

This disables IPv4 on the interface with the bad route and re-enables DHCP. For manually entered IP addresses:

```
interfacetofix=`netstat -r -f inet | grep "0&" | awk '{print $NF}'`
interfacenametofix=`networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder | grep "$interfacetofix" -B1 | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 2-10`
interfaceIP=`networksetup -getinfo "$interfacenametofix" | grep "^IP address:" | awk '{print $NF}'`
interfaceSubnet=`networksetup -getinfo "$interfacenametofix" | grep "Subnet mask:" | awk '{print $NF}'`
interfaceRouter=`networksetup -getinfo "$interfacenametofix" | grep "^Router:" | awk '{print $NF}'`
networksetup -setv4off "$interfacenametofix"; networksetup -setmanual "$interfacenametofix" "$interfaceIP" "$interfaceSubnet" "$interfaceRouter"
```

For full details on what does what and why I use this specific code:
http://briancanfixit.blogspot.com/2014/05/fix-juniper-network-connect-on-mac-bad.html

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the field: **Netif**,

disabling the proper interface according to **Netif** to clean up the invalid routes. (e.g., on my MacBookPro Retina, **en0** is wi-fi)